# User Interface Icons

Tags: user-interface, windows-vista, icons

Does anyone know where I can find well-designed user interface icons?

I'm looking for 16x16 icons for a toolbar that I'm designing.  I really enjoy the OS style, but I need some that will fit well with Vista.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a list of all my icon links, some for free and some for pay:

- [www.mezzoblue.com/icons/chalkwork/collection/](http://www.mezzoblue.com/icons/chalkwork/collection/)
- [www.iconpot.com/](http://www.iconpot.com/)
- [www.icondock.com/](http://www.icondock.com/)
- [www.axialis.com/free/icons/](http://www.axialis.com/free/icons/)
- [www.webiconsets.com/](http://www.webiconsets.com/)
- [www.planeticons.com/](http://www.planeticons.com/)
- [www.jasperhauser.nl/icon/iconkit.html](http://www.jasperhauser.nl/icon/iconkit.html)
- [www.ionworx.com/icons.html](http://www.ionworx.com/icons.html)
- [commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Nuvola_icon](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Nuvola_icon)s
- [www.iconsreview.com/](http://www.iconsreview.com/)
- [www.icojoy.com/](http://www.icojoy.com/)
- [www.glyfx.com/index.html](http://www.glyfx.com/index.html)
- [www.glyfz.com/glyfz2007.htm](http://www.glyfz.com/glyfz2007.htm)
- [www.fasticon.com/stockicons.html](http://www.fasticon.com/stockicons.html)
- [www.ndesign-studio.com/stock-icons/](http://www.ndesign-studio.com/stock-icons/)
- [www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/)
- [www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/09/03/symbols-buttons-and-icons-for-free/](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/09/03/symbols-buttons-and-icons-for-free/)
- [www.windows-icons.com/](http://www.windows-icons.com/)
- [www.readyicons.com/](http://www.readyicons.com/)
- [www.icondesignlab.com/portfolio-toolbar-icons.php](http://www.icondesignlab.com/portfolio-toolbar-icons.php)
- [stock-icons.luckyicon.com/](http://stock-icons.luckyicon.com/)
- [sweetie.sublink.ca/](http://sweetie.sublink.ca/)
- [www.ndesign-studio.com/resources/mini-pixel-icons/](http://www.ndesign-studio.com/resources/mini-pixel-icons/)
- [www.freeiconsweb.com/index.html](http://www.freeiconsweb.com/index.html)
- [www.websiteicons.com/about/cipres](http://www.websiteicons.com/about/cipres)
- [tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project)
- [www.iconfactory.com/stockicons](http://www.iconfactory.com/stockicons)
- [www.awicons.com/stockicons/?discount=stockico2](http://www.awicons.com/stockicons/?discount=stockico2)
- [www.interfacelift.com/icons-win/index.php?sort=date](http://www.interfacelift.com/icons-win/index.php?sort=date)
- [www.marvilla.us/](http://www.marvilla.us/)
- [www.yellowicon.com/index.php](http://www.yellowicon.com/index.php)

Needless to say ... I like looking at icons!

Another great site (Aug 30, 09) ...

- [www.tripwiremagazine.com/icons/design/50-top-free-icon-resources.html](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/icons/design/50-top-free-icon-resources.html)

Comment: I only know a few of them, but +1 for shear quantity. Nice one.

Comment: Dang, I feel like I should downvote my own answer after seeing this one ;)

Comment: @routeNpingme Like I said ... I have a bit of an icon fetish! =)

Answer (score 6):

[FamFamFam](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/) of course

Comment: see you FamFamFam and raise ya FamFamFamFam Simon... (it's like the old joke goes, I know how to spell banananananana, I just don't know when to stop...)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, to get you started...

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Clear

Answer (score 3):

If you have Visual Studio and are just looking for standard Windows application icons you might want to check the icons coming with Visual Studio. Per default they are placed into:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\VS2008ImageLibrary
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this are on mattruma's list...

Not free but priced well and very high quality:

- http://www.iconshock.com/

And some others in no particular order:

- http://www.iconexperience.com/
- http://www.icondrawer.com/
- http://www.icongalore.com/
- http://stockicons.com/
- http://iconfactory.com/

Comment: Those are some great sites ... nice icons!